# How to read Mifare Cards with Different Keys?

Tags: mifare

I'm trying to read a Mifare card (sector 15, block 0).

I have two cards.

#### Card A

It has the default Key A `FFFFFFFFFFFF`.

#### Card B

It has the default Key A `D3F7D3F7D3F7`.

To read Card A, using the ACR122U reader, I'm using the following APDUs:

apdu_authenticate_sector = [0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x60, 0x00]
apdu_read_block = [0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x10]

How would it be to read card B?

I tried something like:

apdu_authenticate_sector = [0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x61, 0xD3, 0xF7, 0xD3, 0xF7]

But I can't authenticate.